# How to get the error marker on a specific array element

Tags: xtext, xtend

I have written a validation which works fine but I want to know how I can set the error marker(the red line drawn underneath the input) at the proper position.
The Problem is that the part of my grammar looks like that:

```
Declaration:
name = ID "=" singleContent=VarContent (OPERATOR nextCon+=VarContent)*
;
```

The validator now detects an error at a specififc element of nextCon so my question is how can I refer to that particular element so the error-functions knows where to draw the line.

The input I validate looks like that:

```
var = 3 * 4 + -var2
```

The "-" within var2 is wrong and therefore I want to highlight the error right there or highlight the complete "-var2" statement.

Greetings Krzmbrzl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your validation rule, you can use one of the overloaded variants of `error(..)` or `warning(..)` that accepts an index in case you have a multi-value feature like `nextCon`.

The grammar snippet that you posted indicates that you don't use a tree to parse an expression but a list of values. You may want to have a look at [the documentation](https://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation/307_special_languages.html#expressions) to learn how to fix this.

Comment: What is the advantage of using a tree in this case? I mean it works just fine as it is...

Comment: A tree would ensure that you get proper precedences in case of + and *

Comment: Ah okay now I understand... Thanks for that tip but for my purpose I don't need to care about precedence at all since I only want to create an elicited plug in for an existing language (and I won't implement a compiler)